# Hindi fonts in xterm

Tags: fonts, xterm

xterm fails to display the Indian fonts (Hindi).
Instead, it displays the garbage character.

I'm using xterm version 293 on LFS

I copied sample hindi text from [here](http://www.loksatta.com/viva-news/when-clearing-doubt-in-classroom-798172/)

Answer (score 2):

It is not only for **Indian fonts**.Instead you can say **combining characters**. Most of the Indian language scripts are combining characters :-) .For example Kannada,Hindi,Tamil,Malayalam etc,etc. almost all :-)

`Xterm` only supported Level 1 (no combining characters) of ISO 10646-1 with fixed character width and left-to-right writing direction[No Arab characters,I guess it is urdu that is from right to left]. In other words, the terminal semantics were basically the same as for ISO 8859-1, except that it can now decode UTF-8 and can access 16-bit characters.

The `xterm` version that comes with XFree86 4.0 or higher includes `UTF-8` support. To activate it, start `xterm` in a UTF-8 locale and use a font with `iso10646-1` encoding, for instance with

```
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8 xterm -fn '-Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-SemiCondensed--13-120-75-75-C-60-ISO10646-1'
```

If you are not using `XFree86 4.0` or newer, then you can alternatively download the latest `xterm` development version separately and compile it yourself with

`./configure --enable-wide-chars ; make`

or alternatively with

`xmkmf; make Makefiles; make; make install; make install.man`.

If you do not have `UTF-8` locale support available, use command line option `-u8` when you invoke `xterm` to switch input and output to UTF-8.

**For more info on this refer the following link:**

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html